# How to create POST method in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on my college website project we created APIs for store data and retrieve data from the Database. Now I am integrating this API in to the admin panel but ***I don't know how to create a POST method or NewsAdd method.***

This is my controller code.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using BACKEND_HTML_DOT_NET.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;
using RestSharp;

namespace BACKEND_HTML_DOT_NET.Controllers
{
    public class News : Controller
    {
        private string apiBaseUrl = "https://localhost:44374/api";
        HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
        private List<NewsVM> newsVMList = new List<NewsVM>();

        public IActionResult NewsList()
        {
            var restClient = new RestClient(apiBaseUrl);
            var restRequest = new RestRequest("/GetAllNewsDetails", Method.Get);
            restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            RestResponse response = restClient.Execute(restRequest);

            var content = response.Content;

            var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResponse<List<NewsVM>>>(content);
            newsVMList = user.data;
            return View(newsVMList);

        }
        
        public IActionResult NewsView(int id=0)
        {
            NewsVM newsVM = new NewsVM();
            newsVM = newsVMList.Where(m => m.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(newsVM);
        }

        public IActionResult NewsAdd()
        {
           return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my cshtml page

```
@model List<BACKEND_HTML_DOT_NET.Models.NewsVM>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "NewsAdd";
}

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- <h3 style="margin-left: 15px;">DEPARTMENT</h3> -->
    <section class="content" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a href="@Url.Action("NewsList","News")">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">

                        <li style="margin-left: 00px;"><i class="nav-icon fas fa-minus-circle"></i></li>
                        <li style="margin-left: 00px;">Back to Details</li>
                    </ol>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card card-primary">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Add New News</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-header -->
                    <!-- form start -->
                    <form id="newsaddform" asp-action="NewsAdd" asp-controller="News" method="post" role="form">
                        @using(Html.BeginForm()){

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputText">ENTER TITLE OF NEWS</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="ENTER TITLE.. ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                   <label for="description">ENTER DESCRIPTION OF NEWS</label>
                                   <textarea type="text" name="description" class="form-control" id="description" rows="4" placeholder="Write content"></textarea>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <div class="input-group col-12">
                                <div class="col-sm-6"><button type="submit" id="sub" class="btn btn-primary float-right col-md-2">Submit</button></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6"><button type="reset" class="btn btn-default col-md-2">Clear</button></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        }
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

@section script{

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {
        //console.log( "ready!" );

        $('#newsaddform').validate({
          rules: {
            "title": {
                 required: true                
             },
             "description": {
                 required: true
             }

          },
          messages: {
            "title": {
                 required: "this field is required"
             },
             "description": {
                 required: "this field is required"
             }
          }
         

        });

        $('#newsaddform').submit(function(e) {

        //prevent Default functionality
        e.preventDefault();


        if($('#newsaddform').valid()){

        var dataForm = new FormData($('#newsaddform')[0]);
        

        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("NewsAdd","News")',
                type: 'post',
                crossDomain: true,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                dataType: 'application/json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                data: dataForm,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
        });
        }

    });


    });

</script>

}
```

This is the model class

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BACKEND_HTML_DOT_NET.Models
{

```
public class NewsVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedDateInt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedDateInt { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Mark corresponding action with [`HttpPostAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.httppostattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and make it accept desired model.

Comment: And here are the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-6.0) which you can find useful

Answer (score 0):

When you select form submit(`method="post"`),you can send the post request directly by clicking the `Submit` button(`type="submit"`), this will submit the content of your input box by default,and don't need to send the post request through `Ajax`.

Below is my test code,you can refer to it:

View:

```
@model _2022072601.Models.NewsVM

    <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- <h3 style="margin-left: 15px;">DEPARTMENT</h3> -->
    <section class="content" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a href="@Url.Action("NewsList","News")">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">

                        <li style="margin-left: 00px;"><i class="nav-icon fas fa-minus-circle"></i></li>
                        <li style="margin-left: 00px;">Back to Details</li>
                    </ol>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card card-primary">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Add New News</h3>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-header -->
                    <!-- form start -->
                    <form id="newsaddform" asp-action="NewsAdd" asp-controller="Home" method="post" role="form">
                        @using(Html.BeginForm()){
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputText">ENTER TITLE OF NEWS</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="ENTER TITLE.. ">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                   <label for="description">ENTER DESCRIPTION OF NEWS</label>
                                   <textarea type="text" name="description" class="form-control" id="description" rows="4" placeholder="Write content"></textarea>
                               </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <div class="input-group col-12">
                                <div class="col-sm-6"><button type="submit" id="sub" class="btn btn-primary float-right col-md-2">Submit</button></div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6"><button type="reset" class="btn btn-default col-md-2">Clear</button></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        }
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult NewsAdd()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult NewsAdd(NewsVM newsVM)
{
    return Json(newsVM);
}
```

Test Result:
[image]

For more details, please refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-6.0).